# How to deny USA users except google bots?

Tags: .htaccess, seo

As for one of my friends request i had to build a website for 3 countries in 3 sub-domains.
Like

```
au.example.com
us.example.com
in.example.com
```

All these three has **common contents and some unique contents**.All the traffic comes from a particular country will redirect to the related subdomain.

My problem is the google indexing. As all the traffic comes from USA will directed to `us.example.com`,google bots will index only `us.example sub-domain`.But there are lot of other contents at `in.example.com`. so how can I let the google to index my other 2 subdomains?

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you doing your location-specific sorting?

What you'll have to do is add an exception based on something, probably based on the user-agent.

However, Google has searches for all languages, so you really shouldn't worry about it. Their version of search for AU will crawl AU, etc. If you want to allow Google to index AU for its US search... that might get you in a bit of trouble with Google (and honestly, would defeat the purpose of what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I am using Geoip to identify the country code and redirect users for the related subdomain. Did you mean if i didn't do anything then the google's specific version of a country will be index my pages is it?

Comment: That is correct. Google has a version for just about every language, and each of those usually present themselves as being from that area. You might also consider a check in which you look at the defined language/locale of the user.

Comment: If you want to achieve this goal, i would recommend host each country specific sub-domain on server located in respective region. Once it is done, submit each sub-domain into google webmaster tool and set target location. You can also set this by placing geo meta tags into home page of your website.